# How navigate back with new argument in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, arguments, android-jetpack-compose

I want to navigate back with different input argument.

I have a `ParentScreen` and it is using input argument `arg` (=`"first"`). Code navigates from parent to child by sending `newArg` (=`"firstsecond"`) on button press. When navigating back from child to parent I want parent's input `arg` to be `"fistsecond"`.

Below I wrote the code (it is not working) to show what I want.

```
@Composable
fun ParentScreen(
    nav: NavHostController,
    arg: String = "first"
) {
    val newArg = arg + "second"
    
    Button(onClick = { 
        nav.navigate("child/$newArg") {
            popUpTo("parent/$newArg") {
                saveState = true
            }
        }
    }) {
        Text(text = arg)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you may want to do is launch the parent composable as single top, and when navigating from child composable, you can send the new argument and launch it as single top again. Here is how you can achieve if you are using [compose navigation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/navigation);

You can launch ParentScreen for the first time like this;

```
navController.navigate("parent/first") {
    launchSingleTop = true
}
```

Then navigate to ChildScreen as usual;

```
navController.navigate("child/firstSecond")
```

In ChildScreen navigate to ParentSceen like this, this will remove the ChildScreen from the nav stack and launch the ParentScreen as single top, resulting only ParentScreen in the stack with new parameter;

```
navController.navigate("parent/$newArg") {
    launchSingleTop = true
    popUpTo("child/{someArg}") {
        inclusive = true
    }
}
```

Full code here;

```
@Composable
fun SampleNavHost(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    navController: NavHostController,
    onBackClick: () -> Unit,
    startDestination: String = "start_dest",
) {
    NavHost(
        modifier = modifier,
        navController = navController,
        startDestination = startDestination
    ) {
        composable("start_dest") {
            Button(onClick = {
                navController.navigate("parent/first") {
                    launchSingleTop = true
                }
            }) {
                Text(text = "move to parent")
            }
        }
        composable("parent/{someArg}") {
            val arg = it.arguments?.getString("someArg").orEmpty()
            ParentScreen(
                title = arg,
                navStackSize = navController.backQueue.size.toString(),
                onButtonClick = {
                    navController.navigate("child/firstSecond")
                }
            )
        }
        composable("child/{someArg}") {
            val arg = it.arguments?.getString("someArg").orEmpty()
            val newArg = arg + "second"
            ChildScreen(
                title = arg,
                onButtonClick = {
                    navController.navigate("parent/$newArg") {
                        launchSingleTop = true
                        // this will navigate current composable from stack when navigating
                        popUpTo("child/{someArg}") {
                            inclusive = true
                        }
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ParentScreen(
    title: String,
    navStackSize: String,
    onButtonClick: () -> Unit,
) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Parent Screen, stack size: $navStackSize")
        Button(onClick = onButtonClick) {
            Text(text = title)
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ChildScreen(
    title: String,
    onButtonClick: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    Column {
        Text(text = "Child Screen")
        Button(onClick = { onButtonClick(title) }) {
            Text(text = title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, this not something that I am looking for. I would prefer to find a solution to change the value of argument in back stack